# Do Jews consider Jesus to be a magician?

Tags: christianity, sorcery-magic-kishuf

With black magic you can do amazing things, including bewitching people's senses, for example, to see things, hear things and feel certain sensations, whether emotionally or physically.  Often when a prophet was sent to his people, they accused him of magic; for example, Pharaoh and his chiefs accused Moses of being a magician, and the Egyptians followed them. And they treated the signs of God with arrogance and called Moses a liar.  Well, Jesus raised the dead, healed those born blind and a leper. He even made birds out of clay and gave them life. And people witnessed these signs and miracles. Do Jews consider these miracles as black magic?

(To anyone who answers this question: Could you please not use in your argument that Christians consider Jesus to be God/divine and that is the reason for not accepting him? I do not consider Jesus to be God/divine.)

Comment: Is there a (non-Christian) source that these seeming miracles happened? Perhaps they were made up later, and there's nothing to explain.

Comment: THere's something about Judaism everyone should know - it does not deal with Jesus at all. It's off-topic, as it has no practical implications whatsoever. Who he was (if anything) and what he did is not discussed or witnessed beyond the fact that he was sentenced for witchcraft and passed to Romans for execution.

Comment: The notion of "magic" here is a bit confusing. There is an idea within Judaism (in its mystical branch) that one can effect "miracles" by the use of the name of God. There is a medieval story which explains that the miracles performed by Jesus were performed by secreting the divine name and exploiting it.

Comment: Never mind the alleged actions recorded in the "gospels", but the birds made of clay story is from a much later infancy "gospel", regarded as spurious by most literary critics.

Comment: He likely never existed to begin with

Answer (score 11):

> The miracles Jesus preformed cannot be preformed by magic, it simply is not possible. You cannot raise the dead, heal those born blind or the leaper by magic. Jesus even made out of clay birds and gave them life. And people witnessed these signs and miracles.

You started this off with a huge swath of assumptions which can easily be disproven by the Torah.

**Firstly**, You ***can*** do all of these things with black magic, at least the Torah tells us it is possible and forbidden. The Torah specifically warns against a spectrum of dark arts, idolatries, and witchcrafts which all fall into this category.

> Let no one be found among you who consigns his son or daughter to the fire, or who is an augur, a soothsayer, a diviner, a sorcerer,one who casts spells, or one who consults ghosts or familiar spirits, or one who inquires of the dead. **(Deut 18:11)**

The Oral Torah explains that this also involves the raising of the dead (necromancy). Rashi specifically touched upon this.

> Rashi: "or a charmer"
>   One who collects snakes, scorpions or other creatures to one place. 
>   "a pithom sorcerer" - one who raises the [spirit of the] dead, and it speaks from his [the sorcerer’s] armpit.
>   "a yido’a sorcerer" - one who inserts a bone of the animal called yido’a into his mouth, and the bone speaks by means of sorcery.
>   "or a necromancer" As, for example, one who raises [the dead spirit] upon his membrum, or one who consults a skull. **[(Source)](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/2280404/jewish/Beware-the-Charmer.htm)**

**You cited the story of Jesus molding a dove from clay and animating it to life.** This is a known concept in the mystical traditions and it relates to the sages having discovered divine processes for animating life into clay. [**The Golem of Prague being one of the more famous stories of such a creature.**](http://www.aish.com/atr/Golem.html)

Jesus did nothing that distinguished himself from various other figures beyond presenting himself as a false fulfillment of the Mashiach prophecy and declaring himself God in flesh. Miracles are miracles, and they all belong to Hashem regardless of whose hand is used. Dark magic is dark magic regardless of what you use it for and to whose benefit.

**Beyond that point, we know for a fact that the writings of the New Testament were written hundreds of years after Jesus walked the earth.**

[**The earliest manuscript that exists is dated 150-250 years after Jesus.**](https://www.christianitytoday.com/ct/2018/may-web-only/mark-manuscript-earliest-not-first-century-fcm.html) Since this book was rehashed and edited so many times, King James organized a council to formulate a "finalized" and uniform version of the book in 1611. ***(Seriously, 1611)***

The Council of Nicea (325 CE) (which canonized the NT) edited out various other writings and contradictory narratives and books in order to create a uniform text. So many different folks had so many different interpretations and themes of what exactly Jesus was and what he did that they had to have the Church literally hand-pick what stayed and what went.

- Jesus was claimed to have communed with an army of dragons in a deleted Bible story. **(The Gospel of Pseudo-Matthew, Chapter 18)**
- Jesus straight up murdered a child. **(Infancy Gospel of Thomas 4:1)**
- Jesus convinced a snake which had bitten a child to suck out its poison. **(First Gospel of Infancy 18:13-16)**

So can you see my issue with the claim of ***"Look at the amazing things that Jesus did! Look at everyone who witnessed this! It has to mean something!"***

But then you ignore the fact that if the original New Testament had not been edited in the first place, you would have a Jesus who was a dragon-taming, snake- conversing, child-killing whatever. We know nothing about Jesus beyond his name and beyond what the Rabbis spoke about him. The New Testament is a mishmash of conflicting stories and eyewitness accounts and themes which not could not give a clear picture of what Jesus was thematically, and which also blatantly misquoted the Torah to meet its own needs.

> “For they did not continue in My covenant and I did not care[9] for
>   them…” **[Hebrews 8:9]**
>
> “My covenant which they broke, although I was a husband to them…”
>   **[Jeremiah 31:32]**

**[(Source)](https://jewsforjudaism.org/knowledge/articles/why-jews-cannot-accept-the-new-testament/)**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about what counts as reliable witnesses, text alterations, and related topics has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86220/discussion-on-answer-by-avri-do-jews-consider-jesus-to-be-a-magician).

Comment: I understand the desire to paint another religion in a disparaging light, but the dragon thing is just a translation issue. The writer of that gospel references psalms 148:7 and apparently translates Taninim as dragons.

Comment: The statement, "You can do all of these things with black magic" is incorrect. Ibn Ezra says that the Torah outlaws magic not because it is real but because it is false. G-d does not desire that we waste our desires over stupidity. Rather, we are obligated to use our intelligence. Simply stated, magic does not exist.

Comment: @TurkHill Ibn Ezra is wrong, magic is definitely real and there are many examples of magic discussed in the Talmud and other Jewish texts. The reasons for why one shouldn't do magic is because its harmful and brings evil, not because its fake.

Comment: @setszu The Ibn Ezra (Leviticus, 19:31) says, "Those with empty brains say 'were it not that fortune tellers and magicians were true, the Torah would not prohibit them.' But I (Ibn Ezra) say just the opposite of their words, because the Torah doesn't prohibit that which is true, but it prohibits that which is false. And the proof is the prohibition on idols and statues....."

Comment: @TurkHill Ibn Ezra projecting again. Torah prohibits lies, but Torah also prohibits evil. Magic is not a lie, but it is evil. And I never made the argument that "were they not true, they wouldn't be prohibited" by the way. Also idols were often trapped d*mons I think. So stop with the nonsense, Ibn Ezra, Rambam, etc. are in my view, some of the worst and most nonsensical and heretical writers in the history of Judaism. Also "But I (Ibn Ezra) say just the opposite of their " - who cares, his words are just his own opinions, they are not absolute authority. So rejected, and bye.

Comment: @setszu The ibn Ezra was a celebrated Jewish author and Maimonides was one of the most learned and celebrated of the Jewish rabbis. They were both rationalists. Regarding idols. Torah disagrees with you. Psalm 115:4–8: "Their idols are silver and gold, the work of human hands. They have mouths, but do not speak; eyes, but do not see." This description doesn't sound like a description of trapped demons. Maimonides felt that demons do not exist. And magic does not exist. Rambam was not a heretic.

Comment: @TurkHill Oh you are so confused. Ibn Ezra's and Rambam's reputation is irrelevant, they were horrible heretics who denied things in the Torah. There's no such thing as "rationalist", everyone used rationality up until then too - they were just wrong bc they lived detached from reality, playing concept games in their minds. Rambam was a heretic & his feeling are irrelevant - d*mons are 100% real, existing spiritually & possibly physically. Magic exists, you don't even understand what magic is. Magic works by draining spiritual energies, making pacts with d3mons, etc. - it brings evil.

Comment: @TurkHill As for the Pslam - the reason I think is because by that point, the idols of the past (trapped d*mons) have been obliterated and removed by G-d, blessed be He. As such, only the inanimate statues were left. There were multiple reasons for why idolatry was evil, and both such types of idols were evil.

Comment: @setszu Rambam denied the concept of an anthropomorphic God. If that makes him a heretic then so be it. Regarding demons and magic. There's no evidence that there's things work. They are wishful thinking. You need to demonstrate that these things work before you can suggest we put blind faith in these items.

Comment: @TurkHill Rambam was not necessarily a heretic for that, though G-d, blessed be He, was so gracious & good that He came to us and communicated in ways that we could understand. He was a heretic for other things. There is both evidence of d*mons & magic if one knows where to look, but more than anything, its acknowledged in the Torah and thus its true, no blind faith. Just bc u don't know them, doesn't mean its false. They're reality, not wishful thinking. They've been demonstrated for 1000s of years in history, & thankfully we mostly got rid of that sinful behaviour. This convo ends here too.

Comment: @setszu Why is Rambam a heretic to you? I imagine that he is a heretic because he was a big rationalist. There is no evidence for demons. Talmud Gittin 66a states that shadim are only found in caves, mountain tops, deserts and at night. These are all places of isolation. This causes man to believe he sees others in his imagination. They are illusions.

Comment: @setszu The rabbis say that to see a demon you must kill a cat and put sand in the floor near your bed. Killing a cat is disgusting. No one would do this. And, even then, they say we'd only see the footprint of the demon the next morning, meaning, that they don't exist. The rabbis knew this.

Comment: @TurkHill That is a massive misunderstanding of Gittin 66a - rereead it, they're literally not saying that. He was not a heretic for rationalist - I already explained that "*rationalism*" is nonsense. There is evidence for dmons, also in the Torah, etc. so its true. The stuff about the cat is wrong, that's just one way & a horrible one bc one would be comitting a sin. Dmons may not necessarily leave footprints, and do not physically have to appear always, etc. You don't know what the Rabbis knew, just by the fact that we have secret teachings like Zohar. So wrong.

Comment: @setszu The Zohar is a pious forgery. I understand Gittin 66a, correctly. The rabbis did not believe in demons. You still have not explained why Rambam is heretic. And your disparagement of rationalism is shocking. People who lay no claims to reason for themselves, are not able to prove by reason, this, their assertion; and if you hawk about something superior to reason, it is a mere figment, and far below reason.

Comment: @TurkHill Zohar seems to trace back to before 2nd Temple & is legit bc its secretly passed down teaching until it was okay to reveal it, very common in the times. Ppl who received the Torah I think believed in dmons as Leviticus discusses. Rambam is a heretic bc of a myriad of his beliefs which contradict the text of the Torah & interpret it wrongly to suit the times & motives He exaggerated and justified lying, etc. "Rationalism" is nonsense, I explained this like 3 times by now. And if u think I just reject logic/reason & thats what you got from the entire convo, then idk what to say.

Comment: @setszu I am a Rational Torah Jew, so I accept rationalism and I am a fan of Maimonides. Maimonides would vomit at your use of the term "rationalism." The belief in demons is superstitious. The Zohar dates to the 13th century. Moses de León's wife admitted he made it up.

Comment: @TurkHill There is no such thing as a "Rational Torah Jew". 4th time I'm saying this stuff. D*mons are real, you can't even fathom what superstition means. Rambam himself didn't get what he was doing and the consequences it would have. Lol at the "rationalism" stuff for him. The ideas of Zohar date long before then. If the stuff about his wife is true, it was probably due to pressure she experienced, for the concepts and writing seem to have continuity back to the 2nd temple period and it kinda marches the historical context.

Comment: @setszu If I had more time we could go through the Zohar and show that it is entirely man-made, a pious forgery. His wife wasn't under pressure. She admitted that he made it up. I know you feel emotional to this book, so, I'll leave it there. Regarding demons, there's no evidence. No one's ever seen one. Surely,  the experience and observation of all mankind, in almost all ages, is enough evidence to sufficiently demonstrate that angels and demons do not exist. Besides, why would God create evil "unseen" forces?

Comment: @setszu If there is no such thing as a "Rational Torah Jew" or "Rationalism" then there is no rationale to the universe and there is no God. The fact that there is a rationale to the universe and its laws, proves that there is an intelligent being. God gave us reason and - God has not given man reason to embarrass him, but to prevent his being imposed upon by imaginary forces such as demons and devils. You could say it a hundred times, it would not change the fact.

Comment: @TurkHill Go repent immediately, how can you say something so sick like denying the existence of angels which have been written about for so long and seen by people and are literally in the Torah. Think about how a Holy Guardian Angel that you probably have and is watching over you right now feels. Obviously there are dmons too that's in the Torah as well and people have seen them too and been influenced by them sadly and more. These are the facts, and they aren't merely forces, but literal entities, which can be both physical or transcedental. Educate yourself.

Comment: @TurkHill It wasn't G-d, blessed be He, who created dmons I think, they were created due to evil that humanity brought in after the fall. They work with S@tan to cause evil, but they will be destroyed eventually and world with return to a state of purity. They're not merely forces, and they're partly transcedental & partly physical like almost everything in some sense within reality. Lots of people saw dmons and dmonic possession. The wife could've felt pressured. I also dont feel particularly emotional abt Zohar but ok. U need to study more history an youll see angels/dmons in other places.

Comment: "If there is no "Rational Torah Jew" or "Rationalism" then there is no rationale to the universe and there is no God"-That's a lot of assumptions that you have to prove. There can definitely be a "rationale", but finite human minds can never fully figure it out, just taste samples of it-"rationalists" shouldnt get drunk on it. G-d, blessed be He, is not bound by any of this. There are also different proofs for G-d, & also people might contest your explanation. Practically everyone uses rationality, but rationality must always be subservient to the Torah. Following Torah doesn't embarrass G-d.

Comment: @setszu Regarding angels. God is not a Pasha surrounded by servants that carry out the Pasha's commands. God has no need for assistants! Yes, tradition came up with the idea that there are angels, meaning messengers from God. But they should not be understood as figures outside natural law. Natural law is fixed and needs no change. If one wants to think of the existence of angels, think of the natural forces such as rain, snow, the laws of gravity, etc.

Comment: @setszu In other words, angels refer to natural forces, “He makes His angels winds; His ministers flaming fire” (Psalms 104:4). Additionally, Rambam says that when angels are mentioned in Torah, the story must describe a  vision, as angels do not exist in the physical existence.

Comment: @setszu We agree that we can never fully understand the universe. However, God gave us reason, for a reason (no pun intended), to figure things out. And Satan is not a devil. In Judaism the satan is a servant of God. But of course I do not think any spiritual being exists but God. This is monotheism.

Comment: @TurkHill Those are not natural forces in the Pslam lol, they're products of what angels as entities/beings have done with the help of G-d. Are you at all aware of the divine council theology and what that means, with it being composed of different beings, why G-d talks with S*tan in Job, etc.? G-d might not need them but he has them. It's not tradition that came up with it, but angels are literally in the Torah. The Torah and other sources explicitly state that angels have a physical form, etc. just like humans. They exist outside "natural law" and natural law is not necessarily fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146890/discussion-between-turk-hill-and-setszu).

Comment: @TurkHill G-d, blessed be He, can change the "natural law" and avoid it as He wishes. Possibly servant, but that's incomplete. And there is the d*vil in Judaism, but S*tan can simply be a title. Monotheism means belief and worship of one and only one G-d, blessed be He, not in disbelief in literally any other transcedental entity/being. Universe can never be fully understood, and the Torah is the truth that we otherwise couldn't have known, so we always keep "rationality" as a mere tool under the Torah. Reason is to be used to figure out if someone is a false prophet also for example.

Comment: @setszu I wrote you in the chat.

Comment: @TurkHill I'm not particularly interested to even click on the link. I already know that you are ridiculously wrong, but I simply have to refute your points for anyone who may read this later.

Comment: @setszu In this case, I'll post here what I post on the chat: God is all-knowing and an all-knowing being does not need a council to confide in. And natural law is fixed. They must be as immutable as their immutable author. We can deduce that these laws are perfect because God is perfect — the laws of nature were established by God; therefore, the laws of nature are perfect. Any defect to these laws implies that God did not have the foresight and wisdom to create perfect laws beforehand.

Comment: @TurkHill He doesn't merely confide in the council & even if He may not need them the Torah says that He has them. You have no proof that natural law is fixed. Are you aware of that processes to perfection can occur bc humans introduced sin due to their free will? "as immutable as their immutable author" Proof? Its not necessarily true at all for it would put the laws on the same level as Him. He created perfect laws & created humans with free will (maximizing goodness), which humans ruined, but over time can be restored to maximal perfection while He saves everyone thus maintaining perfection

Comment: @setszu We know that whatever is of God’s doing is unalterable by man beyond the laws which the Creator has ordained. These laws are perfect because they have been ordained by God. Spinoza calls them perfect: "Now all these texts (Jewish text) teach most distinctly that nature preserves a fixed and unchangeable order, and that God in all ages, known and unknown, has been the same; further, that the laws of nature are so perfect..." In summary, God is perfect — the laws of nature were established by God; therefore, the laws of nature are perfect.

Comment: @TurkHill Spinoza was literally excommunicated lol. The laws are perfect, but humans introduced impurity and evil into the sacred space. I'm not so sure that the texts teach a fixed and uncheangable order for G-d, blessed be He, can change the laws if He wants to - He possibly just hasn't though. One could consider "G-d, blessed be He, due to his all-powefulness, can break any naturalistic law" to be a law. Therefore, should he want to make an exception or change any law or cause a miracle, He can do so. That is a part/component of the perfection IMO - the Divine touch.

Comment: @setszu "The laws are perfect, but humans introduced impurity and evil into the sacred space." Good that you admit they were at least once perfect. Now we're getting somewhere. My argument has been that God cannot produce or perform a miracle and, I will give you my reasons for saying it.

Comment: @TurkHill You are now denying all-powerfulness of G-d, blessed be He. Stop with the blasphemy and evil and go repent.

Comment: @setszu God is perfect — the laws of nature were established by God; therefore, the laws of nature are perfect.
But admitting miracles, the syllogism should be that these laws were once perfect but have been altered (by a miracle); therefore, the alteration of these laws is imperfect. Or, the laws have been altered and the alteration has been for the better; therefore, the first establishment was imperfect. Thus it appears, from a syllogistical as well as other methods of reasoning, that miracles derogate from the perfection of God.

Comment: @setszu No, you are now denying the perfection of God. It is as if you were to say: "God Almighty wants to wind up his watch from time to time: otherwise it would cease to move. He had not, it seems, sufficient foresight to make it a perpetual motion."

Comment: @TurkHill I'm not denying His perfection. Ability for miracles to occur is a part of the perfection of the laws. Since He is perfect, His laws, including right now, are perfect too. Period. Laws of nature also are not the same as ALL laws, etc. Reflect on your foolishness. That His laws are perfect doesn't imply that He can't perform miracles. Like I said before, humans messed up, but through the grace of His and His perfect laws, we are still able to continue to exist and redeem ourselves bc He saves us through miracles, etc.

Comment: @setszu "Since He is perfect, His laws, including right now, are perfect too." Good, we're getting somewhere now. If you admit his laws are perfect, then you agree that there is no need for miracles. All that is needed has been placed in the laws of nature.

Comment: @TurkHill My guy, I'm trying to tell you that miracles are a part of this entire thing because His direct involvement and ability to modify *is* *good* in an of itself. Its a part of the perfection. The fact that miracles happened and that they're described in the Torah proves that they're part of the perfection. To not have the ability to conduct miracles and modify His own laws would contradict His all powerfulness as well.

Comment: @setszu Nope. It is a contradiction in terms to call any miracle perfection. If miracles were needed then it means the laws were once perfect but have been altered and are now imperfect. Or, the laws have been altered and, if this alteration has been for the better; then it means that the first establishment of those laws were imperfect.

Comment: @TurkHill All the relevant things have been explained to you. Go ponder on them since you're incorrect.

Comment: @setszu I think your the one making blanket statements here. Miracles are a demonstration to God's imperfection. God cannot change. You've need to think man!

Comment: @setszu Maimonides assumes that God is perfect and any change in God is a change from perfection to imperfection and if God changes then God is not perfect.

Comment: @TurkHill Miracles are a demonstration of His goodness and power. I already replied about the stuff for change in a different comment under the ghosts topic. Also capacity for change of state within context can be interpreted as part of goodness. Its not change of His intrinsic essence, but change within the derived world. Creation of creation of creation, etc. G-d, blessed be He, does not change. None of this contradicts anything I said before. Its also possible that change as such can only seem to us, since He knows everything, and only reveals things.

Comment: @setszu If God cannons change than there is no room for miracles. God cannot change means there is no change in God. Maimonides makes it clear that God never undergoes a change, whether in relation to his essence or the nature of things. God does not tinker with his creation. He is not like the plumber who just return, form time to time, to fix his prior work.

Comment: @TurkHill Rambam is wrong in his understanding and I explained it in a different comment.

Answer (score 5):

This question you have asked is not specific to Jesus. Why not ask the same question about other "miracle-workers" throughout time? Although flipping the question doesn't necessarily answer it, it does help us get somewhere. I ask you this: what do Christians think of the "miracles" of Mohammad? The answer is that since Christians reject the validity of the Qur'an, they also reject the validity of the miracles recorded within.

Since Judaism does not accept the New Testament as valid, the miracles within the New Testament are rejected as well. We don't have to say they were "black magic" because we believe they never happened.

Comment: @CliffordDurousseau Though Toldoth Yeshu is indeed a Jewish source, I would hardly call it authoritative or say that it depicts the majority of Jewish thought on Jesus.

Comment: @CliffordDurousseau A bunch of Jews reading it on Xmas doesn't make it any more authoritative. Give me a Rabbinic source that advocates it.

Comment: When you say, We believe they (the miracles of Jesus) never happened, are you saying (1) that you speak for all Jews (the Jewish scholar, Joseph Klausner, for example, says, 'This power Jesus had' [Jesus of Nazareth, p.270] and Geza Vermes, The Changing Faces of Jesus) and (2) that the miracles recorded in the first four books of the Christian NT are lies?

Comment: @CliffordDurousseau You still have yet to quote an authoritative Jewish source. To answer your first question, I am speaking through the voice of at least one majority view within traditional Judaism. To answer your second question: yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @ezraWhat source(s) say that the miracles of Jesus never happened?

Comment: Clifford there isn't any historical proof for his existence so anything claimed he did would also be pointless

Answer (score 1):

Avri’s answer is correct and much more detailed than mine. However, there is one opinion that does indeed say that Jesus could have been guilty of witchcraft.

Tosfos to Sanhedrin 37b DH miyom shecharav ask why the Gemara says that “even after the Beis HaMikdash was destroyed” the judgement of the four death penalties is still carried out by G-d through other means; the Sanhedrin voluntarily gave up the ability to administer the death penalty forty years earlier, so why does the Gemara say only once the Beis HaMikdash was destroyed? About halfway into the piece, they write:

> וי״ל מ״מ כשהיו רואים צורך שעה היו חוזרים ללשכת הגזית כי ההיא עובדא
>
> And there is to say that, nevertheless, when they would see that there was a need, they would return to the Lishkas HaGazis [to administer the death penalty], like in “that incident.”

Tosfos seem to be referring to a censored story on 43a; you can find this story in Oz v’Hadar, New Vilna, and Sefaria.

What’s the reason I bring up this Tosfos? Because from the fact that they insist that this story took place during those forty years - from 30 CE to 70 CE, give or take - indicates that the ישו mentioned therein may be Jesus according to them, who was killed in 34 CE.

The relevant quote from 43a is as follows:

> בערב הפסח תלאוהו לישו והכרוז יוצא לפניו מ' יום ישו יוצא ליסקל על שכישף והסית והדיח את ישראל כל מי שיודע לו זכות יבא וילמד עליו ולא מצאו לו זכות ותלאוהו בערב הפסח
>
> On Erev Pesach, they hanged Yeshu. The announcer went before him 40 days [and announced]: “Yeshu is going to be stoned on that he committed witchcraft, that he enticed [to sin], and that he enticed [to idolatry]. Whoever knows a merit for him, come and say it for him.” They did not find a merit, and he was hanged on Erev Pesach.

I should emphasize: most opinions disagree with this reading of the story, saying emphatically that Yeshu as used here is not Jesus, on the grounds that it was after the Sanhedrin stopped administering the death penalty. With Tosfos opening the door, it’s certainly possible that the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: +1 for the second part of your answer which is a straightforward answer - but in my opinion the date 34 CE is totally irrelevant because the Talmud considers Jesus to be a student of Yehoshua ben Perachya. Who are these "most opinions" who say this doesn't refer to the Jesus? As far as I know, Jewish historiography (e.g. Seder Hadorot ג'תרע"א) assume that Jesus lived long before 34 CE. If you interpreted the ההוא עובדא of Tosafot correctly (and I can't suggest an alternative), that complicates things - either the Yeshu of 43a isn't Jesus, or Tosafot does somehow share your date of 34 CE

Comment: @ba 1 CE of the Gregorian calendar refers to the years since Jesus’ birth. 34 CE is the year in which he was crucified. The reason the date is important is because if it’s before 30 CE you don’t need Tosfos to validate this reading of the Gemara, and if it’s after 70 CE, Tosfos don’t help; by noting that it’s in 34 CE I make clear that it’s within the 40 years Tosfos refer to. I’d be curious to see the passage in Seder HaDoros, though, if you have a link to it. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus#Passover_and_crucifixion_in_Jerusalem) gives a date of c. 30 CE.)

Comment: Jesus is usually considered to have been born some time before 1 CE so that his life can overlap with Herod. This is still a century later than the Jewish sources give.   If Tosafot have a date of 30-70 CE for the crucifixion, *and* they are also referring to this case when they say ההוא עובדא, then you are correct. The question is how Tosafot, who didn't have access to Wikipedia, would have had such a date against all of the other sources.

Comment: The link to Seder Hadorot is [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A3_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99_%D7%96) (I couldn't put it in either of my other comments because of the character limit), but Seder Hadorot is one example of many Jewish history books which give this date

Comment: @CliffordDurousseau Tosfos is a plural noun and therefore gets a plural verb.

Answer (score 0):

I. Christian Literature

*Justin Martyr, *Dialogue with Trypho, A Jew* 69.7:

> ‘The spring of living water which gushed forth from God in the land destitute of the knowledge of God, namely the land of the Gentiles, was this Christ, who also appeared in your nation, and healed those who were maimed, and deaf, and lame in body from their birth, causing them to leap, to hear, and to see, by His word. And having raised the dead, and causing them to live, by His deeds He compelled the men who lived at that time to recognise Him. But though they saw such works, they asserted it was magical art. For they dared to call him a magician (μάγος) and a deceiver(πλάνος) of the people.’

*Origen, *Against Celsus* 1.28:

> ‘After she [Mary] had been driven out by her husband and while she was
> wandering about in a disgraceful way she secretly gave birth to Jesus…
> because he was poor he [Jesus] hired himself out as a workman in Egypt,
> and there tried his hand at certain magical powers on which the Egyptians
> pride themselves; he returned full of conceit because of these powers, and
> on account of them gave himself the title of God.’[12]

II. Islamic Literature

*The Qur'an

The Qur'an provides an account of Jesus’ healings and raisings from the dead and adds:

> ‘those who disbelieved among them said: This is nothing but obvious magic’ (5.110).

III. Jewish Literature

**Toldot Yeshu*:

> After King Jannaeus, his wife Helene ruled over all Israel. In the Temple was to be found the Foundation Stone on which were engraved the letters of God's Ineffable Name. Whoever learned the secret of the Name and its use would be able to do whatever he wished. Therefore, the Sages took measures so that no one should gain this knowledge. Lions of brass were bound to two iron pillars at the gate of the place of burnt offerings. Should anyone enter and learn the Name, when he left the lions would roar at him and immediately the valuable secret would be forgotten.
>
> Yeshu came and learned the letters of the Name; he wrote them upon the parchment which he placed in an open cut on his thigh and then drew the flesh over the parchment. As he left, the lions roared and he forgot the secret. But when he came to his house he reopened the cut in his flesh with a knife an lifted out the writing. Then he remembered and obtained the use of the letters.[6]
>
> He gathered about himself three hundred and ten young men of Israel and accused those who spoke ill of his birth of being people who desired greatness and power for themselves. Yeshu proclaimed, "I am the Messiah; and concerning me Isaiah prophesied and said, 'Behold, a virgin shall conceive, and bear a son, and shall call his name Immanuel.'" He quoted other messianic texts, insisting, "David my ancestor prophesied concerning me: 'The Lord said to me, thou art my son, this day have I begotten thee.'"
>
> The insurgents with him replied that if Yeshu was the Messiah he should give them a convincing sign. They therefore, brought to him a lame man, who had never walked. Yeshu spoke over the man the letters of the Ineffable Name, and the leper was healed. Thereupon, they worshipped him as the Messiah, Son of the Highest.
>
> When word of these happenings came to Jerusalem, the Sanhedrin decided to bring about the capture of Yeshu. They sent messengers, Annanui and Ahaziah, who, pretending to be his disciples, said that they brought him an invitation from the leaders of Jerusalem to visit them. Yeshu consented on condition the members of the Sanhedrin receive him as a lord. He started out toward Jerusalem and, arriving at Knob, acquired an ass on which he rode into Jerusalem, as a fulfillment of the prophecy of Zechariah.
>
> The Sages bound him and led him before Queen Helene, with the accusation:**"This man is a sorcerer** and entices everyone." Yeshu replied, "The prophets long ago prophesied my coming: 'And there shall come forth a rod out of the stem of Jesse,' and I am he; but as for them, Scripture says 'Blessed is the man that walketh not in the counsel of the ungodly.'"
>
> Queen Helene asked the Sages: "What he says, is it in your Torah?" They replied: "It is in our Torah, but it is not applicable to him, for it is in Scripture: 'And that prophet which shall presume to speak a word in my name, which I have not commanded him to speak or that shall speak in the name of other gods, even that prophet shall die.' He has not fulfilled the signs and conditions of the Messiah."
>
> Yeshu spoke up: "Madam, I am the Messiah and I revive the dead." A dead body was brought in; he pronounced the letters of the Ineffable Name and the corpse came to life. The Queen was greatly moved and said: "This is a true sign." She reprimanded the Sages and sent them humiliated from her presence. Yeshu's dissident followers increased and there was controversy in Israel.
>
> Yeshu went to Upper Galilee. the Sages came before the Queen, **complaining that Yeshu practiced sorcery** and was leading everyone astray.

---

Answer (score -1):

There is a story about a person, who may or may not be THE Jesus*, who used to hang around the Temple. Somehow he got into the Holy of Holies while the Kohen Gadol was doing the Yom Kippur service. He may have been using a pulley operated maintenance box. He heard the Kohen say a powerful name of God. The trick is, only when the Kohen is in the inspired state inside the room does he know the word. Jesus carved it into his arm and took the word outside and did miracles with it. Thus J did use magic.

*Just like the third guy (Onkelos) in the story with Titus and Bilam may or may not be Jesus but probably is. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onkelos)

Comment: I'm never heard either of the stories you refer to.  Can you elaborate on them?  The first one doesn't sound Jewish, and I don't know what you're referring to with the second one.

Comment: The second story is well known and is from Gittin. Looking for reference to the first one.

Comment: Gittin says that the Onkelos story is about Jesus?  If you can find a specific reference I'd like to see it for myself.

Comment: It is deliberately unsaid but everyone knows who it is, including Christian censors.

Comment: What is the source of this tale of j-sus sneaking into the Holy of Holies? How could that be possible?

Comment: There was a dumbwaiter system for workers to do maintenance on the temple without necessarily being kohanim. There is a picture book by the Temple Institute that shows them. He could have snuck in using that. I'm still looking for the source of the story.

Comment: I imagine the origin of the story comes from a Jew reacting to the Christian championing of "https://biblehub.com/isaiah/49-16.htm"

Comment: @Monica Cellio - The first story is from Toledot Yeshu. See the recent two-volume critical edition by  Michael Meerson and Peter Schafer and others.

Comment: @Monica Cellio - For an online version, see _[Toldot Yeshu](http://jewishchristianlit.com/Topics/JewishJesus/toledoth.html)_.

Answer (score -2):

https://youtu.be/ZQgtCO6RJOM

This shiur by Rabbi Yehoshua Zitron says that there is not a single evidence that Jesus ever existed. And, for the miracles,  not a single witness was ever cited in the so-called "New Testament."

Comment: @ Rh Haokip  The twenty seven books of the Christian New Testament testify that Jesus existed. These pieces of literature were all written in the first century.  In addition, there is the testimony of Josephus in his great work, Antiquities of the Jews. -- The Christian New Testament cites the twelve apostles (emissaries) as witnesses of the miracles of Jesus.

Comment: the new testament itself is heresy. it  is the same as i go and make a new book and write, that another person starts a new cult and then call it "Very new testament" and quote it everywhere. Is that valid at all?!

Comment: Rh Hatop  You do not address the two points I adduced above: That there are 27 books + Josephus the Jewish historian who attest that Jesus lived, and that there were the twelve witnesses to the mitracles.